# How is using OIDC more advantageous compared to SAML?

Tags: openid-connect, saml, mobile-application

When i read the advantages of OIDC over SAML, all the documents say that OIDC can be used on mobile (native) apps or SPAs. But as far as i know, the most popular way to use OIDC on mobile  apps is to use webview or launch a separate browser. But both these options would work with SAML as well. So how using OIDC is more advantageous compared to SAML?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is necessarily more advantageous. It depends on your requirements.

Regardless of the protocol, delegated authentication typically means being prompted, in a browser window, to login at the identity provider/authorization server.

If you're only interested in authentication and not authorization, I think either OIDC or SAML is suitable.

However, if authorization is required to access a REST API, OIDC has the advantage of being built on top of OAuth. An access token, returned by the OpenID provider, can be subsequently submitted as a JWT when making REST API calls.

One big advantage of SAML is that, from my experience, it's much more widely in use. A 3rd party may dictate the use of SAML rather OIDC.

You could also consider some hybrid solution. For example, you may decide to use OIDC internally and then have some sort of authentication protocol converter to handle 3rd party SAML identity providers. There are various commercial and open-source options available.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer stated, it depends on what your use-case is. If you are a new developer and are implementing an SSO type of service, I would recommend SAML as there are many more resources available to help. OIDC does not provide the same amount of authorization data as SAML does. If that is not necessary for your use case and you understand the Oauth flows, OIDC will be a good fit.

I would like to correct a couple of things. OIDC on a native application doesn't use webview, due to security vulnerabilities. i.e. user can't see the redirect url and the application is able to see the information being passed. Which is what Oauth was developed to avoid.

An OIDC provider that is following the spec will use system browser so that the cookies can be shared across resources as well as being able to pass the information without the application being able to see it. The value of the native app flow going this way is the ease of use of refresh tokens.

OIDC does provide a lighter load, as the JWTs passed are not as resource intensive to process as the XML used by SAML. OIDC also allows the use of scopes by users and groups which is similar to SAMLs use of assertions.